# IntelliJ's IDEA and Eclipse on the same project

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, intellij-idea

Hi  I'm currently working on an android project with a group of developers using both Eclipse and IntelliJ.  We're using SVN as our repo.  It seems like every time someone using eclipse checks in they break the IDEA people and vice-verse.  I was wondering if anyone had any recommendations on what files we should ignore from SCM and any other advice on making this process smoother?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest keeping IDE specific project files out of versioning. I have few Android projects where I use Intellij IDEA and Eclipse interchangingly and they seem to be playing well with each other.

Here is what I have in the git repository:

```
.gitignore
AndroidManifest.xml
ant.properties
build.xml
proguard.cfg
project.properties
res/ folder
src/ folder
```

Comment: An Eclipse project without the .project and .classpath files checked in is a real pain to manage across a team. Those files are specifically designed to be shared (checked in) and to not interfere with any other tools. If you're experiencing problems with other IDEs, these Eclipse files are NOT the cause (unless that tool is specifically trying to read or use them).

Comment: actually...IDEA is trying to use the .project and .classpath files so maybe I should figure out a way to ignore those from IDEA.  But I agree that they should probably get checked in.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to give advice without knowing more details about what "breaks." But I can tell you that for Eclipse you need to have the files `.project` and `.classpath` checked in. If there's a .`settings` directory, that should be checked in also. These files are Eclipse-specific and won't affect IntelliJ or any other tool.

Comment: E-Riz you're right.  The reason for our issues was that IDEA was somehow merging the eclipse settings into the IntelliJ module dependencies (something related to the eclipse android adt package - sorry don't remember the details).  We were fixing this every time locally by ignoring the .project and .classpath files from IntelliJ.  However, we were forgetting to check in the .iml file and .idea directory into svn so the changes never got propagated across the team.  A pretty rookie (which I am) mistake I must admit.  Does that make sense to you? I'm opened to other suggestions.  Thanks!

Comment: This is not accurate. IntelliJ might change the .classpath file if you instruct it to use the .classpath file for module dependencies.

Comment: @YoelGluschnaider, that has to be an explicit choice by the user, and he knows what he's doing when he makes that choice. Otherwise, the Eclipse files *are* ignored by, and have no affect on, IntelliJ. In fact, the IntelliJ documentation even describes the scenario where the two sets of IDE config files live side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/github/gitignore. Just add the IDEs, languages, and frameworks you're using. The Eclipse and IntelliJ ignores are in the `Global/` folder.